# How to tell Helm not to run a job

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I am trying to make a Kubernetes deployment script using helm.
I created following 2 jobs (skipped the container template since I guess it does not matter)

templates/jobs/migrate.yaml

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: {{ .Release.Name }}-migrate
  namespace: {{ .Release.Namespace }}
  annotations:
    "helm.sh/hook": post-install
    "helm.sh/hook-weight": "10"
    "helm.sh/hook-delete-policy": hook-succeeded
spec:
  ...
```

templates/jobs/seed.yaml

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: {{ .Release.Name }}-seed
  namespace: {{ .Release.Namespace }}
spec:
  ...
```

First job is updating the database structure.
Second job will reset the database contents and fill it with example data.

Since I did not add `post-install` hook to the seed job I was expecting that job to not run automatically but only when I manually ask it to run.
But it not only ran automatically, it tried to run before migrate.

How can I define a job that I have to manually trigger for it to run?
In vanilla kubernetes jobs run only when I explicitly execute their files using
`kubectl apply -f job/seed-database.yaml`

How can I do the same using helm?

Comment: Just remove those files from the `templates` folder....Basically when you run `helm install` in the background it's going to took all the files in templates folder, and replace the values with the template engine, to create the final yaml files...then it's going to send all those manifests agains the k8s api server(just like `kubectl apply` on all of them).

Comment: But I need them to be templated. I have about 5 volumes and 20 env variables that need to be provided to each job.

Comment: here is what i know: `job` is a k8s concept. when you create it, it runs to termination based on whatever is defined in it's spec. `hook` is a helm concept. hooks can use jobs and will make sure they run on specified points of the installation process. for example your first example is a post-install and runs after the helm chart is installed. as far as i know there is no manual execution of jobs. you can perhaps install a resource that has an api that you can manually invoke, or use cronjob to have scheduled execution..

Comment: @murtiko Neither of them work for me, since those jobs are just simple maintenance scripts: "initialise database, create admin user, take website down for mantenence, put it back up, flush caches, make a backup, load a backup, etc." it makes no sense to create a server for handling those, especially since some of them will be used just once when deploying the project.

Comment: Ok, so this should helps then `suspended jobs!!!` https://kubernetes.io/blog/2021/04/12/introducing-suspended-jobs/

Comment: Can I run a suspended job multiple times?
From documentation it seems like a one time job that cannot be rerun like normal jobs

Answer (score 3):

Replying to your last comment and thanks to @HubertNNN for his idea:

> Can I run a suspended job multiple times? From documentation it seems
> like a one time job that cannot be rerun like normal jobs

It's normal job, you just editing yaml file with the `.spec.suspend: true` and it's `startTime`:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: myjob
spec:
  suspend: true
  parallelism: 1
  completions: 5
  template:
    spec:
      ...
```

> If all Jobs were created in the suspended state and placed in a pending queue, I can achieve priority-based Job scheduling by resuming Jobs in the right order.

More information is [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/job/#suspending-a-job)

Comment: I'm not sure if it helps but there is also the `{{ Release.IsUpgrade }}` variable to determine if it is a upgrade or first install. You can use this to set suspended depending on the action you take